# How to mount a single hard disk from a former QNAP NAS with a DRBD volume under Ubuntu for data recovery?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

Under Ubuntu, how to mount a single disk from a defunct QNAP NAS with a DRBD volume with a software RAID 1, for the purpose of data recovery?

QNAP NAS, which was using software RAID1:

- https://www.qnap.com/en/product/ts-453a

Hard Disk:

- one of formerly two 2 GB SSHD Seagate 2,5" SATA

The Seagate is connected by SATA to a Ubuntu running intel / amd pc.

I creating mount point on Ubuntu:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/my_mountpoint
```

Perhaps, the follow sources can give hints for a solution:

- http://www.drbd.org
- https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/ubuntu-ha-drbd
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DRBD
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/drbd.conf.5.html

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/ubuntu-ha-drbd